# how overriding in Prestashop works

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

When we mimic a function in our overriding class, does Prestashop simply replace the whole function with the original one or does it append to it. for eg.

```
/mymodule/override/classes/Product.php:

class Product extends ProductCore {
   public function add() {
      // some function
   }
}
```

Is it going to append `// some function` or is it going to replace the whole class `add()`

Comment: Did you made some tests before asking your question? Plus it is not a Prestashop specific question but a simple PHP heritage usage. You should check for classes heritage and specifically `extends` keyword in PHP.

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre thanks for the help. There's another thing I wannna ask, do you happen to know a way to create a new `Product type` like: `simple, pack, virtual`. If yes, can you tell the procedure

Comment: Hummm there is no simple way to do this unfortunately. Those product types are hardcoded everywhere in Prestashop, you would need to override a lot of classes. I would not advise you to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that it will replace the whole function. You should look into [PHP classes heritage mechanism](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php).

You still have the possibility to execute the original Product `add()` method in your override by adding `parent::add()` in your code.

```
class Product extends ProductCore {
    public function add() {
        // do something before adding
        parent::add();
    }
}
```